# AceGen/ AceFem on new M1 Mac

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen, apple-silicon

Apple has updated its processors some time ago and I am curious if AceGen/ AceFem are compatible with this latest generation of the Apple M1 processors? And maybe someone can already report on the performance of these processors. :)
Best,
Max

Comment: Make a link to acegen/acefem and maybe some test code you’d like to see a benchmmark value for, then those of us with an m1 can test and give standard results that make sense to you

Comment: Executable AceFEM is built on OSX 10.14 Mojave and it should work also on higher versions. So far no incompatibility has been reported.

Answer (score 2):

Executable AceFEM is built on OSX 10.14 Mojave and it should work also on higher versions. So far no incompatibility has been reported.

Comment: Hi Prof. Korelc, I just tried to install Ace on my new M1 Mac. Unfortunately the installer says : "Error in installation procedure while performing task: Sorry, but 
your platform MacOSX-ARM64 is not yet supported". Is there any workaround ? I have gcc11 installed as well.

Comment: For now I could 'solve' the problem by using the Mathematica version for the Intel Mac, which to my understanding runs on my M1 Mac through the translation layer Rosetta2. Here, AceGen/AceFEM installs and runs fine.